# selenium webdriver not recognizing button

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been trying to find the button using selenium but i'm unable to figure out why the solutions that i've tried dont work.

```
<div class="k-header k-grid-toolbar k-toolbar">
<button class="k-button k-button-icontext da-toolbar-button" mode="">
    <span class="k-icon da-icon-download"></span> = "Download"
</button>
```

I've tried the following solutions but doesn't seem to work.
by css

```
if(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(".k-button")).size() != 0){
          System.out.println("Element is Present");
          }else{
          System.out.println("Element is Absent");
          }
```

by xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='k-button k-button-icontext da-toolbar-button']//span[@class='k-icon da-icon-download']")).click();
```

by inner text

```
xpath=//button[contains(.,'Download')]
```

by xpath position

```
xpath=//div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/button
```

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting any errors on locating that element? it would be wise to check the presence of any iframes before the element.

Comment: try: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'k-button')]")).click();

Comment: @pcalkins i've tried your suggestion but i still get 
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[contains(@class,'k-button')]"}

Comment: view the page in the browser, then right-click on the button and choose "inspect".  Post that markup.

Comment: <button class="k-button k-button-icontext da-toolbar-button" mode=""><span class="k-icon da-icon-download"></span>Download</button>

its the same thing what i have posted above @pcalkins

Comment: dont think they are any iframes @Sureshmani

Comment: that markup is odd... there is no event handler or id.  Does this button work when you click it manually?  Can you add the js that processes the events here?

Comment: yes it works manually, how can i get the js? @pcalkins

Comment: check the source... you if all you see is an src, you'd have to use that path to download the file.  It'll be in "<SCRIPT>" tag(s).  Look for a script specific for the site.  You may want to just add the whole page's markup here so we can be more helpful.